# Using table joins with ST_DWithin to optimise process?

Tags: postgis, attribute-joins, st-dwithin

I am trying to select all segments (among millions of them) that are less than X metres from a few thousands polygons obtained from a raster dataset (meaning they've got quite a complex geometry - many vertices) OR less than X metres from another set of thousands polygons (less complex geometry). I am attempting to do so using ST_DWithin and a double LEFT JOIN, but it's proving to be very slow (more than 48 hours running and it hasn't finished yet).

Projected Coordinate System (British National Grid)

All 3 tables have a spatial index

---

This is the query I'm trying with:

```
CREATE TABLE result AS
SELECT t1.segments_id , t2.polyg1_id , t3.polyg2_id
FROM segments t1
LEFT JOIN polyg1 t2
ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, X)
LEFT JOIN polyg2 t3
ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t3.geom, X)
```

Once this query is finished I would just need to discard all records from `result` that have no polyg1_id or polyg2_id values.

Is there any better (more efficient) ways to achieve what I'm trying to obtain?

Answer (score 2):

If an existence check is what you're after, better use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.segments_id
FROM   segments AS s
WHERE  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   pt1 AS p
  WHERE  ST_DWithin(s.geom, p.geom, <dist>)
) OR  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   pt2 AS p
  WHERE  ST_DWithin(s.geom, p.geom, <dist>)
);
```

This has two major advantages over `JOIN`s:

- the `EXISTS` will stop the execution of it's statement when it
  encounters the first condition match (`1` -> `TRUE` -> *found a
  match*), thus reduces table traversal significantly when used with an
  appropriate index (like the spatial index and `ST_DWithin`)
- the `OR` will stop the whole block for the current row once the first
  statement returns `TRUE`; again, this will greatly increase
  performance

As a general note, if (non-) existence is what you are looking for, `(NOT) EXISTS` will beat `JOIN`s in most cases.

Comment: I will try this if after a few more hours the query I'm trying has not finished yet (hard to stop a query after 48 hours running!). However, I have been told I should always use joins for this type of queries (I don't really understand the reasoning behind it though)

Comment: 2 INNER JOINS would not work because the first JOIN would not keep all the necessary segments to run the second JOIN.

Comment: From your question I understand you intend an `AND` condition, so a segment must be in proximity of *both* tables to be considered? If so, removing unmatched segments in the first `JOIN` is quite what you want. In your first comment, if you were referring to @Vince's comment on your other question, that is not what it meant; you should explicitly use the `JOIN` syntax instead of listing tables by `,` (which translates into `CROSS JOIN`), and the requirements of your other question is completely different: here, you are specifically looking for the existence of rows by condition.

Comment: Unless you're using a toaster oven as a database server, with a USB 1.0 thumbdrive on a SATlink shared device, 48 hours is 42 hours too long to run this query.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!! It's not AND but OR. Just amended the description.

Comment: For an existence check this would even speed up the process, just replace `AND` with `OR`. I updated that above.

Comment: @PitrakoJunior so how are things going here?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of your update. Will try your suggestion with OR and update this thread with the result.

Comment: After 24h running I have stopped the query. I think I have found a way that requires about 7 hours. It doesn't seem very elegant to me, but it does the job. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have found a fairly fast way to do it (at least compared to what I have been trying with). Basically, I have just split my original query in two.

Instead of:

```
CREATE TABLE result AS
SELECT t1.segments_id , t2.polyg1_id , t3.polyg2_id
FROM segments t1
LEFT JOIN polyg1 t2
ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, X)
LEFT JOIN polyg2 t3
ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t3.geom, X)
```

I have tried with:

```
CREATE TABLE result_1 AS
SELECT t1.segment_id, t2.polyg1_id, t1.geom
FROM segments t1
LEFT JOIN polyg1 t2
ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, X)


CREATE TABLE result_2 AS
SELECT t1.segment_id, t1.polyg1_id, t3.polyg2_id, t1.geom
FROM result_1 t1
LEFT JOIN polyg2 t3
ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom, t3.geom, X)
```

And then I just need to get those segments where either polyg1_id or polyg2_id is populated, and then obtain unique segments (get rid segments with multiple results). Finally I INNER JOIN with the original table of segments to get back the geometries.

```
CREATE TABLE result AS
SELECT t1.segment_id, t1.geom FROM segments t1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT(segment_id) FROM
   (SELECT segment_id FROM result_2
    WHERE (polyg1_id >= 0) OR (polyg2_id >= 0))
    select1)
select2
ON t1.segment_id = select2.segment_id
```

As I said, it seems a bit convoluted and not very elegant, but so far it's proved to be the quickest way.

Comment: Now, I must admit I haven't got the slightest idea why dividing the 2 JOINS into two different queries is faster than having both JOINS into the same query (????). A lot faster actually.